# Bun in VS Code: error "Cannot find name Bun" when using the Bun singleton

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bun

### The problem I'm experiencing

I installed [Bun](https://bun.sh) in WSL and connected to it via VS Code, but when I tried to use `Bun.serve` in my code, VS Code shows an error saying `Cannot find name 'Bun'`. I know this is because VS Code doesn't know that I'm using Bun, but I don't know how I can make VS Code recognize Bun.

### What I tried

I tried installing the official Bun VS Code extension, but the error persisted.
I also searched on Google but I didn't find anything.

### What I was expecting

The error should stop showing and ideally VS Code should provide autocompletion for the `Bun` singleton.

Comment: Have you installed the [bun](https://bun.sh/guides/runtime/typescript) types?

Comment: @Asplund yes i did

Comment: Make sure to restart TS server (ctrl + shift + p). If `npx tsc --noEmit` works, your VSCode is referencing the wrong tsconfig. If not you did not install the bun types correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

have you try this one:

On TS you need to install bun-types as devDependency.

Command:

```
bun add -d bun-types
```

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
        "compilerOptions": {
            "types": [
                "bun-types"
            ]
        }
}
```

Follow this doc: https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/typescript

Comment: As of bun v1.0.19, this answer is no longer correct given that now there is a @types/bun package. See https://bun.sh/blog/bun-v1.0.19#re-introducing-types-bun-formerly-bun-types